# TYPO3 8.7 TCA ext_tables.php check

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I've started a new project with `TYPO3 CMS 8.7 LTS` and I've created my own distribution- (or provider-) extension for `TypoScript`, `TSconfig` and HTML-Templates -- like usual.

At the new `Install Tool` there's a check: **TCA in ext_tables.php check**

```
Extensions change TCA in ext_tables.php
Check for ExtensionManagementUtility and $GLOBALS["TCA"].
```

I've read, that the `ext_tables.php` should be (nearly) empty. So my file only contains the link to my static typoscript file:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Distribution Extension');
```

That's all. But why is the Install-Tool-Check not successful?

I've also [read](http://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/79689/typo3-cms-8-7-1-fehler-bei-den-modulen-protokoll-und-erweiterungen), that this command should be in `typo3conf/ext/distribution_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php`, but If I try, I can't choose my distribution in backend (root template -> include static template) ..?

What is the perfect way to include static template files in TYPO3 8.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the `ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile()` call into `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php` is correct, but keep in mind to clear your system caches (the red lightning) afterwards.

Also keep in mind that `$_EXTKEY` is unavailable in that file, use your extension key in a string instead.

Example:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('distribution_ext', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Distribution Extension');
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, you're very fast ;) my syntax was wrong and I found my mistake a few minutes after asking ... your answer is correct, thanks.